# Когда я пытаюсь установить PySide я получаю сообщение об ошибке

Tags: python, pyside

Пишу в консоль `pip install PySide` и тут у меня ошибка

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Python34\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\formin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-990k0idv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: Removing C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_package
    running install
    running build
    Python architecture is 64bit
    nmake was found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe
    Inserting path "C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release\bin" to environment
    ==============================
    Package version: 1.2.4
    Build type: Release
    Build tests: False
    ---
    Make path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe
    Make generator: NMake Makefiles
    Make jobs:
    ---
    Script directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3
    Sources directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\sources
    Build directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_build\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release
    Install directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release
    Python site-packages install directory: C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release\Lib\site-packages
    ---
    Python executable: C:\Python34\python.exe
    Python includes: C:\Python34\include
    Python library: C:\Python34\libs\python34.lib
    Python prefix: C:\Python34
    Python scripts: C:\Python34\Scripts
    ---
    Qt qmake: C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qmake.exe
    Qt version: 4.8.6
    Qt bins: C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin
    Qt plugins: C:\Qt\4.8.6\plugins
    ---
    OpenSSL libs: None
    ==============================
    Creating build folder C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_build\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release...
    Creating install folder C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release...
    Building module shiboken...
    Creating module build folder C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_build\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release\shiboken...
    Configuring module shiboken (C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\sources\shiboken)...
    Running process: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -G "NMake Makefiles" -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qmake.exe -DBUILD_TESTS=False -DDISABLE_DOCSTRINGS=True -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_install\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\sources\shiboken -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=C:\Python34\python.exe -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Python34\include -DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=C:\Python34\libs\python34.lib -DCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX=_d -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH=yes -DUSE_PYTHON3=ON
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe -- broken
    CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
      The C compiler

        "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe"

      is not able to compile a simple test program.

      It fails with the following output:

        Change Dir: C:/Users/formin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-prn5mkx3/pyside_build/py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/shiboken/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

        Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_ed08c\fast &&   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_ed08c.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_ed08c.dir\build

        Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ed08c.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
                C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe @C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\nmEDAB.tmp
        testCCompiler.c
        Linking C executable cmTC_ed08c.exe
                "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_ed08c.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~1\MIA713~1\Windows\v7.1\Bin\RC.Exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~1\MIA713~1\Windows\v7.1\Bin\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_ed08c.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\nmEDEA.tmp
        LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_ed08c.dir\objects1.rsp /out:cmTC_ed08c.exe /implib:cmTC_ed08c.lib /pdb:C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\pyside_build\py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release\shiboken\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_ed08c.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_ed08c.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_ed08c.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
        LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
        NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
        Stop.
        NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
        Stop.





      CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/formin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-prn5mkx3/pyside_build/py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/shiboken/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/formin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-prn5mkx3/pyside_build/py3.4-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/shiboken/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    error: Error configuring shiboken
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Python34\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\formin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-990k0idv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\formin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-prn5mkx3\
```

Comment: я рекомендую вам установить PyQt5:  `pip install PyQt5
` и  `pip install pyqt5-tools`

Comment: У вас проблема с компилятором Visual C++. Проще всего установить прекомпилированную версию [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyside).